# Create a matrix with conditions on R

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a problem on R. I'm trying to write a function that select all rows that have a value higher than 0 in at least 2 columns. (The function give the right to choose the number of columns that contain a value > 0 ).

Input matrix :

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
row1  0    0    0    2
row2  2    5    4    0
row3  0    0    8    3
```

Output matrix :

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
row2  2    5    4    0
row3  0    0    8    3
```

If someone can help me with that ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
X <- your_matrix

X[which(rowSums(X > 0) >= 2), ]
```

Sorry, I didn't notice the requirement for a function. As Axeman stated, you could wrap this approach in a function as follows:

```
filter_matrix <- function(
        X, n = 2, na.rm = TRUE
    ){
    stopifnot(is.matrix(X) && is.numeric(X)
    stopifnot(is.numeric(n) && length(n) == 1)
    X[which(rowSums(X > 0, na.rm = na.rm) >= n), ]
    }
```

Comment: So `function(X, n) { X[which(rowSums(X > 0) >= n), ] }`. Does one need the `which`?

Comment: How can I put a 'n' parameter by default if the user don't change it ?

Comment: No you don't need the `which`. Nor do you need to wrap it in a function. However, you might want to put `na.rm = TRUE` in the `rowSums`